# Removing default dividers from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I created a custom alertdialog. I used a half-transparent shape for background.
And its button is fully transparent in unfocused state. 
The button is also customized by using a solid colored shape.

My problem is, there are white lines in two sides of the button where the default button originally located.

I tried to manipulate dividers by changing its color, width etc.

I tried:

android:showDividers="none"

But none of my operations worked. 
So I am thinking these two lines may not be dividers.

But I can not find what are these and how to hide them.

Here is my java code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_Organic_Dialog_Alert);

        alert.setMessage(R.string.channel_warning_message);

        alert.setNeutralButton(R.string.okay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //sthLikeDoNothing();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
```

My theme:

```
<style name="Theme_Organic_Dialog_Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/alert_dialog_bg</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Organic_Button_AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/Organic_ButtonBar_AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog_Organic</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance_Organic</item>
</style>
```

And my button styles:

```
<style name="Organic_ButtonBar_AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item> <!-- ButtonBar background transparency -->
</style>

<style name="Organic_Button_AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"> <!-- Custom drawable button -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/alert_dialog_button_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/alert_dialog_button_txt_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">roboto-regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

These are the lines I want to hide:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causes those divider lines. It was because I was setting **Holo** as the parent of my button styles.
Here,

```
<style name="Organic_ButtonBar_AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
```

and here,

```
<style name="Organic_Button_AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
```

Now I removed parents and the lines are gone.